# PHP %20 issue in url and content

Tags: php, url

I am using a little script, and in the generated content I get a %20 instead of a space.

This is the script I'm using:

index.php

```
what is your name?

<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="temp.php?name=">
<input type="text" value="" name="name"  ></input>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" ></input>
</form>
```

and on temp.php

```
<?php
$name = rawurlencode( $_GET['name'] );
echo "<h1>" . $name . "</h1>";
?>

Hello <?php print $name ?> how are you?
```

If I input `Mr Example`, it renders as Mr%20Example.  It does the same for the url `temp.php?name=Mr%20Example`

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the %20 comes because you have used `rawurlencode`

```
$name = rawurlencode( $_GET['name'] );
```

You have to use rawurldecode , it will replace all this kind of character to original character.

```
$name = rawurldecode( $_GET['name'] );
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply and explaining the basics  to me. worked 100%

Answer (score 2):

use this instead

```
<?php
$name =     urldecode($_GET['name'])
echo "<h1>" . $name . "</h1>";
?>
```